# Integrate an autocomplete functionality for neo4j

Tags: angular, spring-boot, neo4j, neo4j-browser

I am currently visualizing a graph from embedded neo4j with d3. Now I want to add a cipher query language to my interface.

One of the functionality that I want to integrate is autocomplete like the one used in neo4j browser. I also want to add suggesting about the node names and relationship name. Do you have any idea how can I do that or should I do it manually by querying the application each time a user write something. 
I am using spring boot for the backend 
I am using angular for the frontend

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j browser is using codemirror for the cypher input, and there is a repository to make the cypher autocomplete : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-editor